# generate textbox dynamically error

Tags: vb.net

I'm using this code on generating textbox by the programatically method, by using  vb.net and i got this error

```
 Dim txt1 As TextBox
 Dim i As Integer = 0
 While i < 5

        txt1 = New TextBox()
        txt1.ID = "myTextBox" + i

        Panel1.Controls.Add(txt1)
        Dim lit As New Literal()
        lit.Text = "<br><br>"
        Panel1.Controls.Add(lit)
        System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(i), i - 1)

    End While
```

error

[image]

Comment: You should write `Option Strict On` at the top of your file (mainly when you are not too experienced). If you would have done that, your code wouldn't have compiled just because of the second line (`Dim i As Integer = 0` is what you should have written). When `Option Strict On` is not written VB.NET allows you to do many not-so-good-things, what might drive you to think that wrong code is actually right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is VB right?

Shouldn't this:

```
txt1.ID = "myTextBox" + i
```

be:

```
txt1.ID = "myTextBox" & i
```

The string concatenation.